# Passing argv and argc to main as an array

Tags: c++, opencv, command-line

I am using opencv, and have a function that takes command line variables:

```
int start(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
    if(parser.has("help")) {
        parser.printMessage();
        return 0;
    }
....

}
```

what I would like to do, is have another function that passes variables to this one, instead of using the command line, as it is now. 
the command line I pass it to run perfectly is:

`-h=6 -w=8 -pf=defaultConfig.xml -t=charuco -v=bmCalib2.mov -sz=0.045 -d=1`

So I have this function:

```
void main()
{
char* passArg[7] = { "-h=6", "-w=8","-pf=defaultConfig.xml", "-t=charuco","-v=bmCalib2.mov", "-sz=0.045", " -d=1" };
        start(7,passArg);
}
```

It compiles and runs, but the results are different (it is a calibration application, the command line calibrates, and the function version does not).

Is this the correct way to send `int argc, char** argv` instead of using command line? 
thank you.

Comment: `void main` is wrong

Comment: is the space in " -d=1" wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, already solved. I needed to adjust my char array to:

`char* passArg[8] = { NULL,"-h=6", "-w=8","-pf=defaultConfig.xml", "-t=charuco","-v=bmCalib2.mov", "-sz=0.045", " -d=3" };`

Obviously the `.exe` is usually the first variable given in a command line launch.

Comment: Should be `const char*` I'm surprised this even compiles, based on the OpenCV docs